# Arch linux: spotify stuck offiline

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, hosts

I have installed spotify on arch linux via yay. When I open spotify it says it is offline even when I have working internet connection and throws **error code: 4**

[image: screenshot]

This is log of `spotify`:

```
spotify: /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by spotify)
/opt/spotify/spotify: /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /opt/spotify/spotify)
/opt/spotify/spotify: /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /opt/spotify/spotify)
/proc/self/exe: /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: no version information available (required by /proc/self/exe)
```

I will not post output of `spotify --show-console` because it contains login tokens and sessions ids.

How can I fix this so spotify can work normally ?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be hopefully solved with one of these three steps:

**1) Add spotify servers to hosts**
You have to add this

```
0.0.0.0 weblb-wg.gslb.spotify.com
0.0.0.0 prod.b.ssl.us-eu.fastlylb.net
```

to `/etc/hosts`

**2) Disable notifications**
Sometime spotify get stuck while trying to make notification and stop loading stuff. You can disable them by adding this

```
ui.track_notifications_enabled=false
```

to `~/.config/spotify/current/.config/spotify/Users/[Some user]-user/prefs`

**3) Updating your system and AUR packages**
To upgrade my system and AUR packages I used:

```
yay -Syyu
```

Comment: You say one of these will help - tried all three and none of them did for me.

Comment: Than your problem has different cause. If you provide more information, I can try to figure out some solution